# I can't see the data I pulled from Firestore without refreshing the page

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
  List<String> docGameInfoId = [];


      getGamesId() async {
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('gameinfo')
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) {
          docGameInfoId = [];
          for (var element in snapshot.docs) {
            docGameInfoId.add(element.reference.id);
          }
        });
      }
```

Here is the code where I am using the gameinfo collection.

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: getGamesId(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: docGameInfoId.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                height: 300,
                child: GetGamesInfo(documentId: docGameInfoId[index]),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
```

Here is the code where I show the selectedGame data I got from Firestore on the main page in the list.

```
 final String documentId;

CollectionReference users =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('gameinfo');
return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data =
          snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return Center(child: Center(child: Text('${data['selectedGame']}')));
    }
    return const Text('');
  },
);
```

My **GetGamesId** document.

I am able to save the data properly and display it on my homepage without a problem. But I can't see the last data I added unless I refresh the page or go to another page and return to the main page. I can also see the last data added when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Streambuilder together with the `.snapshots()` method from Firebase.
Otherwise you will only get the current value from the database at the time when  `.get()` is called, with `.snapshots()` you will listen to any changes.

[Here more info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?hl=en#dart_3)

Comment: I understood thank you. I solved the problem. I am adding the answer to the question as well.

Comment: "I am adding the answer to the question as well." Please don't. That's not how Stack Overflow works. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307553/is-it-better-to-answer-or-edit-your-question-to-post-solution --- If you have an alternate answer, post that as a separate answer to your question. If you want to clarify Max's answer, make/propose an edit to this answer.